# Ammonia _water mixture as VLE fluid in TIL media /Dymola

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

Can you please guide my mistake regarding selecting VLE fluid as ammonia-water mixture and I get the error as following in DYmola, TIL Suit: Check of testingbaseHTHP:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omsRa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHCps.png)

```
The problem is structurally singular.

It has 2390 scalar unknowns and 2376 scalar equations.
The Real part has 2390 unknowns and 2376 equations.
The Integer part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.
The Boolean part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.
The String part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.

The model is not well-posed.
The model has
2352
scalar unknowns and
2338
scalar equations.
Using the given settings of the parameters, the difference could be reduced to
14

Attempting to further localize singularity.

Attempting to further localize singularity.

Attempting to further localize singularity.

Singularity of testingbaseHTHP is in the component boundary4.vleFluid_ph, class TIL.Utilities.Internals.Media.VLEFluid_ph.

The model testingbaseHTHP component boundary4.vleFluid_ph is structurally singular.

The problem is structurally singular for the element type Real.

The number of scalar Real unknown elements are 111.
The number of scalar Real equation elements are 110.

The following variables are considered as unknowns, but are not appearing in the equations.
boundary4.vleFluid_ph.x[]

WARNINGS have been issued.

ERRORS have been issued.
```

I tried to do simulation of ammonia water mixture refrigerant heat pump and got the singularity error in dymola/TIL Suit

Comment: For multi component VLEFluids you need to do some redeclares. See KalinaCycle Example. 
Please share Modelica Code of a small example and which TIL version you are using.